# How to create f-string new line within a list?

Tags: python, f-string

I am trying to use f-string within a list.  I have created a new line variable.  Standard variables work fine but the new line variable does not

```
NL = '\n'
var = 'xyz'
lst = []
print(f'test{NL}new line')
lst.append(f"first line var is {var}{NL}a second line {NL}")
lst.append(f"third line{NL}forth line var is {var}")
print(lst)
```

creates the output

```
test
new line
['first line var is xyz\na second line \n', 'third line\nforth line var is xyz']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What happens when you do for example `print(f"{lst[0]}")` ?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? Like, were you expecting the list to be printed across multiple lines?

Comment: Related? [Why does printing a tuple (list, dict, etc.) in Python double the backslashes?](/q/29245234/4518341)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's working fine**

When a list is printed, strings in the list are shown raw, not printed. If you print the strings one by one, you will see that they print as expected:

```py
NL = '\n'
var = 'xyz'
lst = []
print(f'test{NL}new line')
lst.append(f"first line var is {var}{NL}a second line {NL}")
lst.append(f"third line{NL}forth line var is {var}")
for s in lst:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
test
new line
first line var is xyz
a second line 

third line
forth line var is xyz
```